# startActivity from a custom class

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I have a menu and 5 activities. To avoid repeating the menu code, I have created a public class and call it in every activity:

```
 Testclass testclass = new Testclass(Main.this);
```

...but unfortunately I can't use `startActivity()` in the class. This is my class code:

```
 public class Testclass extends Activity {

     public Testclass(Activity cc) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(cc,Next.class);
            startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Post your `Activity` class. It might be that you've defined `startActivity()` as private or something.

Comment: start your activity with its context. For ex `context.startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this and tell me if it helped you.

```
public class Testclass extends Activity {

     public Testclass(Activity cc) {
         final Context context = Testclass.this.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , Next.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

Comment: what should i write instead of "YourClass" ?

Comment: everything i wrote got ERROR

Comment: YourClass means the Class you are on it. See my post I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the concept of an Activity and its life cycle. You DON'T instantiate the Activity, the Activity has callback mechanisms (onCreate, onResume, etc.) that tell you exactly what to do. You never ever have to call `new Activity()`.
The fact that you're doing 
`Testclass testclass = new Testclass(Main.this);` shows that you have a misunderstanding of this concept: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

To fix your error, read the docs and then it will be clear what is wrong with your approach.

Hint: Your Testclass already IS an Activity, because you inherit from `Activity`.

And next time please provide the whole error log to your problem, so it can give the whole picture of what can be wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this code?

```
startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Next.class));
// "Main" is your current Activity
// "Next" is your next Activity to be opened.
```

I think, it's very simple to use without create a new public class. Please compare your codes with my code above, only one line.

Comment: thanks. i created a new class because I don't want to repeat the codes in other 4 activities

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't use the correct Context to start the Intent.

Instead try

```
{

public Testclass() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,Next.class);
            startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

if the `this` doesn't work either, try `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

#you can used Weak Reference Objects to store Context of Activity class#

```
##in activity class## 

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);


        findViewById(R.id.toNext).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Testclass thread = new Testclass(Activity.this,v);
        new Thread(thread).start();

        }
    }

}

// in sub class
public class Testclass extends Activity implements Runnable {
    View landingPage;

    private Activity activity;

    public Testclass (Activity activity, View landingPage){
        WeakReference<Activity> ActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(Activity);

        this.landingPage = landingPage;
        this.activity = activityWeakReference.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(activity, Next.class);
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                switch (landingPage.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.Next.class:
                        activity.finish();
                        activity.startActivity(activityIntent);
                        break;

                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.